# How to check boundary of array in CUDA Kernel without branch divergence

Tags: cuda

In following kernel, I used `if` statement to avoid out-of-range calculation. But if I understand correctly, the `if' statement will cause branch divergence that will slow down the computation - please correct me if I am wrong here.

My question: How can I avoid the if statement while handing out-of-range calculation in the kernel?

```
__global__ void vector_add(float *a, float *b, float *c)
{
    int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(index < N)
          c[index] = a[index]*a[index] + b[index]*b[index];
}
//kernel call here
vector_add<<< (N + (THREADS_PER_BLOCK+1)) / THREADS_PER_BLOCK, THREADS_PER_BLOCK >>>( d_a, d_b, d_c );
```

Comment: Why do you claim that there is any _divergence branch_ in your execution path? The threads with `index >= N` will just wait or not be launched at all and nothing will be serialized since there is not `else` statement in your code snippet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While it is technically called a "divergence" (because not all threads within a warp evaluate the condition identically), it is *completely* harmless.

The threads that do not evaluate the predicate to `true` will simply get disabled: it's not a performance issue, as those threads are not expected to take part in the computation anyway. You are not losing any actual *work thread*. In the pathological case where `N` is congruent to `1 mod 32` (or whatever the warp size is), there is simply a warp that gets almost completely "wasted", but again, it is not a performance issue.

Warp divergence hurts your performance when threads within a warp take different paths that need to be executed serially. This is not the case here.

Comment: @Cicada While your answer seems correct for the case above, I would rather not to generalize it for different scenarios. Disabled lanes of a warp are precious computing resources that stay unavailable until reaching the re-convergence point. For example, I would prefer to have 32 threads of one warp to do a similar job rather than 32 warps one lane of each doing that job.